# Hibernate query bulk manipulation exception

Tags: java, hibernate

With Hibernate, I am trying to execute a query by setting multiple values from list and executing it at the same time. Here is the code

```
public void savePriority(List<Integer> priorities,int typeid) {
    String sql="update table conf_sr_type_baserule_assoc set n_priority=:priority where n_typeid=:typeid";
    /*System.out.println("sql query in savePriority"+sql);*/
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
    SQLQuery squery=session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    tx.begin();
    for(int priority:priorities){
        squery.setParameter("priority", priority);
        squery.setParameter("typeid", typeid);
        squery.executeUpdate();
    }
    tx.commit();
    session.close();    
}
```

but I am getting an error:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query

Comment: Ahh.. error in query. thanks a lot

Comment: What is the type of input you are trying to pass into "savePriority(List<Integer> priorities,int typeid)" can u give me example

Comment: Use getTransacton() before commit and change your sql query syntax as the answered one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from your SQL query, which is invalid.

It should be:

```sql
update conf_sr_type_baserule_assoc set n_priority=:priority where n_typeid=:typeid
```

instead of

```sql
update table conf_sr_type_baserule_assoc set n_priority=:priority where n_typeid=:typeid
```